# using setAttribute to ID by adding class to it

Tags: javascript, setattribute

I am new to JavaScript.  I am practicing setAttribute by adding a class to an id:

When I click on the button, I want to change the color of the font to red. However, it is not changing.

I borrowed a similar example from w3school, but added an id to it.

HTML:

```
<h1 id = "Hello">Hello World</h1>

<p>Click the button to add a class attribute with the value of "democlass" to the h1 element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
// returns a html element (id)
var $ = function(id) {
return document.getElementById(id);
};

function myFunction() {
$("Hello").setAttribute("class", "democlass"); 
}
```

CSS:

```
#Hello.democlass {
color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1vzmqgqv/

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I would advise you not use $ as your function name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code working good, you need to change **jsfiddle** settings for JavaScript.

Go to JavaScript section then click on settings icon ,Change `LOAD TYPE` to be `No wrap - in <body>`

https://jsfiddle.net/ddg6gdbw/

```js
// returns a html element (id)
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};

function myFunction() {
  $("Hello").setAttribute("class", "democlass"); 
}
```

```css
#Hello.democlass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 id = "Hello">Hello World</h1>

<p>Click the button to add a class attribute with the value of "democlass" to the h1 element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```